# Need an appropriate loader to handle image file

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I would like to import an image.png into an  tag, but I get this error:

```
ERROR in ./src/components/sorciere.png 1:0
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '�' (1:0)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
(Source code omitted for this binary file)
 @ ./src/components/Home.js 6:0-38
 @ ./src/components/App.js 3:0-26 15:17-21
 @ ./src/index.js 1:0-35
```

My js, the image is in the same folder:

```
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import SwipeableTemporaryDrawer from './HomeTiroir'
import ProfilBtn from './HomeBoutonProfil'
import Typography from '@material-ui/core/Typography';
import sorciere from './sorciere.png'

export default function Home (props) {
  return ( <React.Fragment>
    
    <Grid container style={{ height: '100%' }}>      
      <Grid item container style={{ height: 69 }} xs={12} justify="space-between">
        <SwipeableTemporaryDrawer />
        <ProfilBtn />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item container xs={12} style={{ minHeight: 'calc(100% - 119px)' }}>
        <Grid xs={12} md={6} style={{ border: 'solid', padding: '5% 0 0 10%' }}>
          <Typography variant="h1" component="h2" gutterBottom style={{ color: 'rgba(255, 255, 56, 0.911)' }}>
            Le pouvoir des mots
          </Typography>
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={12} md={6} style={{ border: 'solid', padding: '5%'  }}>
        <img src={sorciere}/>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item style={{ height: 50 }} xs={12}>BOT</Grid>
    </Grid>

  </React.Fragment> 
  )
}
```

My webpack.config.js:

```
const path = require("path");
const webpack = require("webpack");

module.exports = {
  entry: "./src/index.js",
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "./static/frontend"),
    filename: "[name].js",
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: "babel-loader",
        },
      },
    ],
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true,
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
      "process.env": {
        // This has effect on the react lib size
        NODE_ENV: JSON.stringify("production"),
      },
    }),
  ],
};
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "frontend",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "webpack --mode development --watch",
    "build": "webpack --mode production"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.3",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.12.1",
    "@babel/preset-react": "^7.12.5",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "react": "^17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.1",
    "url-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^5.4.0",
    "webpack-cli": "^4.2.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.13.0",
    "@material-ui/core": "^4.11.0",
    "@material-ui/icons": "^4.9.1",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.3",
    "hamburger-react": "^2.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  }
}
```

Babel.config.json:

```
{
    "presets": [
      [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        {
          "targets": {
            "node": "10"
          }
        }
      ],
      "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"]
  }
```

I tried to use: `const sorciere = require('./sorciere.png');`
and to install url-loader as you can see in my package.json, followed this instructions here: https://webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/
But always the same result, I must go wrong ...

Can someone help me? Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out [file-loader](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/)

- Install file-loader `npm install file-loader --save-dev`
- Update your `webpack.config.js` file, the rules array specifically with:

```
...
rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpeg|jpg|gif|svg)$/,
        loader: 'file-loader',
        options: {
          name: '[path][name].[ext]',
          outputPath: "imgs",
        },
      },
    ]
```

Check out the [docs](https://webpack.js.org/loaders/file-loader/) for more information.

Comment: Prefer to use Asset Modules https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/#resource-assets in webpack 5.

Comment: Unfortunatly, It doesn't work either with file-loader or Asset Modules...

Comment: @Niko71 what do you get/see this time?